# Возможность оповещения юзера об обновлении программы

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Добрый день. Поставили задачку и меня загнали в тупик. Мне необходимо иметь возможность оповещать юзера об обновление программы способом аналогичным Chrome for iOS.

Т.е. Приложение должно оповестить юзера об обновлении когда тут будет использовать программу. 
[image]

Сделать всплывающие окно или любое другое мелочи. **Проблема заключается в том**, что я не знаю как запросить у AppStore есть ли обновление или нет.

Открыть AppStore по кнопке, при определении что есть новая версия тоже не проблема.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У AppStore есть [API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html), позволяющее искать приложения. Например, этот запрос вернёт вам все приложения, доступные в США, в названии которых есть `chrome`:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=chrome&country=us&media=software
```

Из ответао можно вытащить версию приложения и сравнить с текущей.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно не у AppStore запрашивать, а разместить эту информацию у себя на сервере - используя wsdl\soap например или просто банально проверять по дате создания файла